# How to make Sublime Text 3 compile a specific file in current directory? c++

Tags: c++, build

For example, I have a project with 2 .cpp files and 2 .h files and also main.cpp .

I want to make Sublime compile main.cpp when I press control-B even if the editor if focused in one of the other .cpp or .h files.

I am not too familiar with JSON so I don't know how to modify the build file.

This is the default build file. The problem with this file is that it compiles the file the editor is focused on.

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. The solution was simple. 
In both lines of

```
"shell_cmd":
```

change

```
${file}
```

to the file name you want to always compile.
For example:

```
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"main.cpp\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
```